# Изменить текст при нажатии на кнопку

Tags: c++, qt

При нажатии мышкой на PushButton текст Label должен меняться

```
 #include <QObject>

class change:public QObject{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    QWidget wid;
    QPushButton *push=new QPushButton("button",&wid);
    QLabel *label=new QLabel("label",&wid);
    change(){
        QObject::connect(push,SIGNAL(clicked()),this,SLOT(rename()));
        wid.show();
    }

public slots:
    void rename(){
       label->setText("123");
    }
};
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    change prog;

    return a.exec();
}
```

В итоге вылетают две ошибки: **undefined reference to `vtable for ex'** и **ld returned 1 exit status**
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В самом низу файла добавьте `#include "main.moc"`.
При этом, в настройках проекта галочка Теневая Сборка должна быть сброшена.

В "боевых" проектах пользовательские классы (тем более, наследуемые от `QObject`) лучше объявлять в отдельных файлах.

Comment: >>При этом, в настройках проекта галочка Теневая Сборка должна быть сброшена.<< — совсем не обязательно...

Comment: В принципе, согласен, но так надежнее )